# Possible conflicts between Lua C++ bindings

Tags: c++, binding, lua

I am currently working on a project. One library I would like to consider using in the future uses ToLua++ as a method of binding Lua. Currently, the library I am looking at is CEGUI, and it uses ToLua++. I am currently considering using LuaBind for the implementation in the project I'm working on. I was wondering if anyone would have any insight as to if that would cause clashes and break things, or if it would work just fine.

Comment: What happens when you tried it?  Did you encounter an error?

Comment: Right now I'm only in the planning phase, I'm wondering whether or not this will cause issues down the line. The current situation of the project is that we are currently using Python, however I am considering attempting to switch the scripting over to LUA in order to add some more security when dealing with user generated content. I am currently trying to find out if anyone has had any problems with this before me, so that way I can plan ahead.

Comment: Please note that the name of the language is Lua, not LUA...

Comment: Sorry, I've had a long day and my brain is fried. I'm sorry about messing up the capitalization, but right now my brain is toast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't define the same Lua entities with both tools, LuaBind and ToLua++ coexist nicely. You can use either tool to add more functions and classes to a module, but you can't add more methods to a class defined by the other tool.